# Implement Activity Indicator in protocol oriented way

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I want to create protocol, that will give me ability to add/remove activity indicator to/from UIViewController and its subclasses, when they conform to this protocol.

so i ended up with code like this

```
protocol ActivityIndicatorPresenter {
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView { get }
    func showActivityIndicator()
    func hideActivityIndicator()
}

extension ActivityIndicatorPresenter where Self: UIViewController {
    func showActivityIndicator() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.activityIndicator.color = UIColor.blackColor()
            self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 80.0, height: 80.0)
            self.activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x:self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, y:self.view.bounds.size.height / 2)
            self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}

    func hideActivityIndicator() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

and in subclass of UIViewController:

```
class MyViewController: ActivityIndicatorPresenter {
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicator { get {return self.spinner}}
    var spinner = UIActivityIndicator()
}
```

Everything works, but i think that returning stored property in computed property's getter is kind of workaround. Is it prettier way to implement it?

Comment: You can't just say `var activityIndicator : UIActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicator()`

Comment: You don't need `: UIActivityIndicator` either, and it should be `let`, not `var`.

Comment: And shouldn't those be `UIActivityIndicatorView`, not `UIActivityIndicator`?

Comment: @AaronBrager No, `let can not be computed properties` and i do need `: UIActivityIndicatorView` in both cases. At least compiler thinks so.
No, it should be exactly `UIActivityIndicatorView`